# How to retrieve file lost by the 'move' command

Tags: command-line, mv

I was moving a [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) file from the disk. Unfortunately, I misspelled the path, and I lost the file Ubuntu.

```
sudo mv /media/creator/sumeeth/software/apache-tomee-1.7.0-plus.tar.gz /~
```

Comment: you probably wanted to move to `~/` (which is your home directory) instead of `/~` (which is a file called `~` in the root directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not delete the file. You just moved it into `/~` (assuming the command did not return any error). Files on Linux can contain any strange characters. Just move the file back with the reverse command:

```
sudo mv /~ /media/creator/sumeeth/software/apache-tomee-1.7.0-plus.tar.gz
```